# Induction coming up with a proposition

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Come up with a proposition **p(n)**, depending on **n**, such that **p(1), p(2),...,p(999)** are `true`, but **p(1000)** is `false`.

I don't really understand the question but my proposition is that `p(n) < p(1000)`
`1 < 1000` is `true` and when it is `1000 < 1000` it is `false`. Do I have to come up with an equation for **p(n)**?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

I take this to mean that you have to define a function p which maps positive integers to propositions, such that the first 999 are true and the 1000th one is false.

The expectation is probably that you give the mapping, and not just properties of the mapping. You use "less than" in your answer. Do you mean this?

> p(n) := "n is less than 1000"

When and positive integer is substituted for n, you get a proposition. The propositions are true for n less than 1000 and false otherwise.

There are infinitely many possibilities, but this might be the most immediate one.